# If I have Pandas installed correctly, why won't my import statement recognize it?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, python-import

I'm working on a project to play around with a csv file, however, I can't get pandas to work. Everything I have researched so far has just told me to make sure that pandas is installed. Using pip I have managed to install pandas just fine. When I try to run my python program and import pandas I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analysis.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I don't know if this is related, but I was trying to see see if this would work with `conda install pandas` however, I get this import error:

(Again, Anaconda is correctly installed on my system)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/conda", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('conda==4.2.7', 'console_scripts', 'conda')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2627, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2287, in load
return self.resolve()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2293, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .main import main  # NOQA
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 46, in <module>
from ..base.context import context
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 18, in <module>
from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, MapParameter, PrimitiveParameter,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 40, in <module>
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedSeq, CommentedMap  # pragma: no cover
ImportError: No module named ruamel.yaml.comments
```

Anyone have a similar experience importing libraries? I have tried to make sure that I have the correct versions for Python3 but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Your Anaconda is for python 2.7, and your python in use is 3.x. This is exactly the issue.

Comment: Does this affect the pandas import? How do I get anaconda to use python 3 by default? I can't seem to get it to work either.

Comment: Just using `conda` won't work by itself either. It doesn't make sense because it has worked in the past.

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python on your system? If so, check and be sure your script is running using the same python you installed pandas under.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the 'lib' folder that pip installs things into has a separate subdirectory for each python environment that you're working with (by default this is python2.7). A simple workaround is to build a virtual environment of python3 and then installing pandas or whatever package you want into it. To achieve this, try the following:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 python3
```

Now, each time you want to pip install a python3 package, run

```
source python3/bin/activate
pip install pandas --user
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I learned that I need to be more careful about which version of Python I'm using for my setup. I appreciate it.

Comment: Another option is to use `pip3` for installing python3 packages. This helps if you want to install something system-wide. However, for development environments, virtualenvs are good for development environments.

Answer (score -1):

Go to powershell on your system and pip install pandas. you will see a successfully installed command. you can install other modules too like matplotlib et al.

Comment: The paths in the stacktrace seem to be from a Mac, so Powershell is probably not available.