# Pandas ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Pandas does not recognize installed matplotlib library

## here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
```

## error is

```
c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in _raise_if_no_mpl()
     55     # TODO(mpl_converter): remove once converter is explicit
     56     if not _HAS_MPL:
---> 57         raise ImportError("matplotlib is required for plotting.")
     58 
     59    
ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting.
```

Comment: You haven’t created any figure object.

Comment: On a jupyter it's works fine

Comment: I tried this on jupyter notebook.It doesn't work. @Cezary.Sz

Comment: On jupyter I need add import pandas and it generate me plot. @Erza

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43422345/7245145 .... check  this way

Comment: This shouldn't happen. I suspect this is a version problem. Which version of pandas are you using and is it possible for you to update it?

Comment: pandas '0.23.4' . I did do pip install  -U pandas

Comment: You may report the full traceback (not just the last line) of `from pandas.plotting import _converter`. It might be that your install is broken.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Installing matplotlib before installing pandas again made it work.

Comment: Jupyter notebook : Install matplotlib .Restart kernal. and import matplotlib before pandas.

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt;
%matplotlib inline

Answer (score 20):

I got the same error in Jupyter Lab. The solution is (**after installing the matplotlib**):

Click `Restart the Kernel` button in the toolbar;

or

Choose menu item `Kernel`=>`Restart Kernel and Run All Cells...`, and click `Restart` in the confirmation dialog

**Done**!

Answer (score 14):

You need to install `matplotlib` for that.

You can type and run the following command in your python shell to install matplotlib

```
python3 -mpip install matplotlib
```

If you are using Anaconda IDE, you can run the following command in the Conda command prompt

```
conda install matplotlib
```

Once installed, re-run the program.

Refer [this](https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html) page for installing matplotlib.

Comment: I do have matplotlib installed. It doesn't get recognized by pandas.

Answer (score 11):

All you had to do is quit Pandas after installing matplotlib and start it again. This way it would see fresh installation. No need to reinstall Pandas.

Comment: if you are using *Jupyter Notebook* you need to go the *Running* tab in the main console and then press the _Shutdown_ button for the notebook that needs to use `.plot`. This step is required after installing `matplotlib` in the desired environment

Answer (score 6):

Just install matplotlib by running this in your terminal:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1):

What I found is that pandas does its own importing using importlib, and it hides issues that are not related to importing matplotlib.

Instead what is really likely happening is that you have missmatched versions of pandas and matplotlib. In my case I had an old Pandas 1.3.5 and matplotlib 3.5.1 and downgrading matplotlib to 3.3.0 did the trick.

So it's not about re-installing matplotlib as much as re-installing the proper version.

You can do the tesrt yourself, by running what the pandas code does

```py
import importlib
importlib.load_module("pandas.plotting._matplotlib")
```

and see what kind of error pops up, which in turns is pivked up as an ImportError because it is in a try except block.