# pandas.DataFrame.plot gives matplotlib import error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have a regression code which I've done all steps but at the end when I want to show predictions in graph, it gives a weird import error!

Here is the code:

```
import math
import numpy as np,datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from pandas.plotting import _converter
import datetime

df['Adj. Close'].plot()
df['Forecast'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

That is not entire code but the parts that I think are related to the error.
 when I run it , I face this error:

```
line 54, in <module>
    df['Adj. Close'].plot()
ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting.
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701688/pandas-importerror-matplotlib-is-required-for-plotting)  question but it didn't help me. I uninstalled the libraries and installed them again but nothing changed.

**Edit:** When I run `import matplot lib` in shell I also face this error:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`

Comment: Close your python shell. Open it again, and run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. What is the output?

Comment: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`. But  I have installed the library!

Comment: Your shell does not seem to agree. Note that if you run `import matplot lib` as you wrote in your post, `matplotlib` will be hardly found.

Comment: but when I used `plt.plot(df['Adj. Close'].tolist())` , it worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib uses Miscrosoft Visual C++ under Windows.
Some parts of that lib are compiled using it, and it needs this redistributable to run
There are more packaged that need it to be installed.
so I tried to install [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
plt.plot(df['Adj. Close'].tolist())
```

Comment: It worked! But what is the problem with my code and why I face error?

Comment: plt.plot() is a method of matplotlib.pyplot. Its arguments are the lists or arrays to be plotted as x and y axis. You used **df['Adj. Close'].plot()** which literally meant x.plot() whereas you wanted to tell plt.plot(x).  Also, df['Adj. Close'] is a column of pandas dataframe which is of type Series. In order to use it as matplotlib plotting argument, you have to convert it to list (or numpy array). You could have also used seaborn as **sns.lineplot(x = 'Adj. Close' , data=df)**

Comment: No. This is ok. see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Comment: The one you are talking about would have been written like this: **df.plot(x=Adj. Close)** because in it you are using pandas plotting feature on dataframe df and using Adj. Close as x-axis.

Comment: Again when I used `df.plot(x=Adj. Close)` I faced the same error!

Comment: Because, it needs y axis to plot with something. If you only need to plot a single column, you need to mention the kind of your plot. See this : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html

Comment: No. I face the error : `ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting.` and It's not related to what you say. I think there is a problem in matplotlib installation but I don't know what. Also see my edit in the question.